# How to return files that have been filtered by multer filefilter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm trying to implement `multer` fileFilter function and it works (it does filter files and files get uploaded) but when I set file filtering `req.files` becomes empty.

```
const extFilter = function (req, file, cb) {

    if(file.originalname.match(/^.*\.(avi|mov|mp4)$/)) cb(null, true)
    
    cb(null, false)
  
}

const upload = multer({ storage: cloudStorage, 
                        fileFilter: extFilter }).array('file')

upload(req, res, function (err) {   
                return res.status(200).send(req.files) //returns nothing
              })
```

Without fileFilter option set the function returns array of uploaded files.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about req.file instead of req.files? (You are defining multer as array('file'), not files)

Comment: 'file' is to reference formData. When you use .single req.file is the uploaded file and when you use .array req.files contains array of uploaded files (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). And as I said, without fileFilter it is working...

Answer (score 0):

The fileFilter function was missing **return** before `cb(null, true)`

```
const extFilter = function (req, file, cb) {

    if(file.originalname.match(/^.*\.(avi|mov|mp4)$/)) return cb(null, true)
    
    cb(null, false)
  
}
```

Otherwise the files get written to the disk because of the first callback but then nothing is returned in `req.files` because of the second `cb(null, false)`.